# App Crash on launch iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode8, appdelegate, nib, rootviewcontroller

I am facing an issue like app get crash on launch, i am trying to navigate to the RootViewController but app getting crash constantly, please check below crash report and specially app get crash only in iOS 10

- Any suggestion

Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'RootViewController'
2016-10-21 18:59:45.588010 Dragon Inn[796:175032] Full Trace:
0   Dragon Inn                          0x00000001000518f0 -[StackTracer generateTraceWithMaxEntries:] + 104
1   Dragon Inn                          0x00000001000a5ac4 handleException + 120
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018975c540  + 644
3   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000188194838  + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x000000018818366c  + 16
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0000000188183234 __cxa_rethrow + 144
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018819471c objc_exception_rethrow + 44
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001896360bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
8   GraphicsServices                    0x000000018b0b9198 GSEventRunModal + 180
9   UIKit                               0x000000018f610628  + 684
10  UIKit                               0x000000018f60b360 UIApplicationMain + 208
11  Dragon Inn                          0x000000010007ff14 main + 124
12  libdyld.dylib                       0x00
2016-10-21 18:59:51.327601 Dragon Inn[796:175032] Condensed Intelligent Trace:
handleException    __cxa_rethrow objc_exception_rethrow CFRunLoopRunSpecific GSEventRunModal  UIApplicationMain main 
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

**APPDELEGATE.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    appUrl = @"";

    strCurrentCity = @"";
    dBI = [[databaseInteraction alloc]init];
    [databaseInteraction check_Create_DB];
    isRootPushed = NO;
    self.checkForNewVersion = TRUE;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    LoadingViewController *masterViewController = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    //Crash Report

    [[CrashManager sharedInstance] manageCrashes];
    [[CrashManager sharedInstance] setCrashDelegate:self selector:@selector(notifyException:stackTrace:)];
    NSString* errorReport = [CrashManager sharedInstance].errorReport;
    if(nil != errorReport) {
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dragon Inn : %@", errorReport]] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"errorText"]];

        NSString *post = [dic JSONRepresentation];
        isJson = TRUE;
        setLoderDown = FALSE;
        req = [[Request alloc] initWithURLByPost:NSLocalizedString(@"crash-report", nil) PostString:post withMethod:@"POST" withDelegate:self withTag:100];
    }

    //=================

    if(devicetoken == nil || devicetoken == NULL) {
        devicetoken = @"";
    }

    //====================



    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        //[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }



    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    return YES;
```

}

Comment: Please share your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunch methods code. I think it is trying to load a "RootViewController", which do not exist

Comment: @Wolverine check updated answer

Comment: Do you have any references to `RootViewController` in the rest of the app? It doesn't appear to be linked to whats in the app delegate, unless you have recently renamed `LoadingViewController` and in that case make sure to clean your build folder and try again.

Comment: @dlbuckley getting crash only iOS 10. :( in iOS9 working fine

Comment: When you say "i am trying to navigate to the RootViewController", what code are you using for that?